# How can I set the workspace numbers to start at 0?

Tags: workspaces, workspace-switcher

I really like the workspace feature, and especially like that I can have workspace numbers listed on the top bar so I always know where I am.  However, workspace numbers always start at 1 and I would prefer them to start at 0.  Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: No, you won't be able to.

Comment: Which flavor of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I would check your current workspaces by installing `sudo apt install wmctrl` then run `wmctrl -d` to list all the desktops.  The numbering is the far left column and the far right is the name of each workspace / desktop.  I use Xfce4 and mine start at number 0 by default.